# HTML List isn't vertically aligned when using floating images

Tags: html, css, image, list, css-float

I have a list with titles, text and images, and sometimes, when there is not enough text, my lists start breaking, ie. the list starts nesting itself.

```
<ul>
   <li><img style="float:left"><h3>title</h3> ... some text here</li>
   <li><img style="float:left"><h3>title</h3> ... some text here</li>
   <li><img style="float:left"><h3>title</h3> ... some text here</li>
</ul>
```

I have an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2z6Zn/246/

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>photo</h3>
    <img src="http://commons.cathopedia.org/w/images/commons/thumb/f/fe/Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG/250px-Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG" />some text next to the photo
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>photo</h3>
    <img src="http://commons.cathopedia.org/w/images/commons/thumb/f/fe/Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG/250px-Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG" />some text next to the photo
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>photo</h3>
    <img src="http://commons.cathopedia.org/w/images/commons/thumb/f/fe/Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG/250px-Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG" />some text next to the photo
  </li>
</ul>
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part you are missing is to clear the `float`s. Use this:

```
li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

and now you will have removed the "nesting".

> Note that while using floating containers, you should always `clear`
>   them before the next container that follows thereby creating a fresh *block
>   formatting context* as it is called. Otherwise you will see
>   unpredictable behavior.

Revised demo below:

```css
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
}
li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<h3>photo</h3>
<img src="http://commons.cathopedia.org/w/images/commons/thumb/f/fe/Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG/250px-Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG" /> some text next to the photo
</li>
<li>
<h3>photo</h3>
<img src="http://commons.cathopedia.org/w/images/commons/thumb/f/fe/Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG/250px-Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG" /> some text next to the photo
</li>
<li>
<h3>photo</h3>
<img src="http://commons.cathopedia.org/w/images/commons/thumb/f/fe/Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG/250px-Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG"  /> some text next to the photo
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, that's great! Thanks, that will get me going!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CSS you have applied in jSfiddle i.e

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
}
```

Instead just add following CSS

```
ul{
display:block;
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Well, no, the picture wouldn't be floating left then.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* This will make every element inside Li align in a line */

 li * {
    display: inline-block;
 }
/* have specifically gave h3 element block property so that it can be in a separate line and serve as a heading */
  li h3 {
    display: block;
  }
```

working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2z6Zn/247/