# Content move down when I apply float property

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have to float the class `time` to right but when I try to float it right, its content moves down. Without float contents look fine but I have to float it.

https://jsfiddle.net/jyckLwv7/

```css
.main-nav {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5e2d91;
  float: right;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.main-nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.main-nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 14px;
}
.main-nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 7px !important;
}
.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0098aa;
}
.main-nav ul li a:active {
  background-color: #6A006A;
}
.time {
  float: righ;
  background: #5e2d91;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #718b88;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 228px;
  height: 33px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://marketinthepocket.com/"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="transaction.php"> Trade Now</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="view.php"> Transactions  </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> Performance </a>
    </li>



    <li><a href="complete.php">History </a>
    </li>
    <li class="time">US Markets Open in&nbsp;<span id="hm_timer" class="style colorDefinition size_sm">08:20:04</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use **`margin-top: -3px`** to fight off that default **`padding`** browsers set to **`body`**, as this padding varies from browser to browser. To achieve a more consistent visual output, you can try normalising this properties with something like:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now, coming to your alignment issue, try removing **`height`** and **`width`** from **`.time`** and **`vertical-align: middle`** to your **`li`** elements.

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/umgreacv/)

**Code:** *(expand the snippet)*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-nav, .main-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-nav {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5e2d91;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.main-nav ul li {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.main-nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 14px;
}
.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0098aa;
}
.main-nav ul li a:active {
  background-color: #6A006A;
}
.time {
  float: right;
  border-color: #718b88;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://marketinthepocket.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="transaction.php">Trade Now</a></li>
    <li><a href="view.php">Transactions</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Performance</a></li>
    <li><a href="complete.php">History</a></li>
    <li class="time">US Markets Open in&nbsp;
      <span id="hm_timer"class="style colorDefinition size_sm">08:20:04</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the `ul` element:

```
.main-nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 7px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.main-nav {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5e2d91;
  float: right;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.main-nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.main-nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 14px;
}
.main-nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 7px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0098aa;
}
.main-nav ul li a:active {
  background-color: #6A006A;
}
.time {
  background: #5e2d91;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #718b88;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 228px;
  height: 33px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://marketinthepocket.com/"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="transaction.php"> Trade Now</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="view.php"> Transactions  </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> Performance </a>
    </li>



    <li><a href="complete.php">History </a>
    </li>
    <li class="time">US Markets Open in&nbsp;<span id="hm_timer" class="style colorDefinition size_sm">08:20:04</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When using `float`ing container, always remember to clear the `float`s- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684091/html-list-isnt-vertically-aligned-when-using-floating-images/39684113#39684113) for more information.

> Note that while using floating containers, you should always clear
>   them before the next container that follows thereby creating a fresh
>   block formatting context as it is called. Otherwise you will see
>   unpredictable behavior.

Instead of `overflow: hidden` you can also `clear` the `float` by using:

```
.main-nav ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
.main-nav {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5e2d91;
  float: right;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.main-nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.main-nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 14px;
}
.main-nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 7px !important;
}
.main-nav ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0098aa;
}
.main-nav ul li a:active {
  background-color: #6A006A;
}
.time {
  background: #5e2d91;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #718b88;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 228px;
  height: 33px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://marketinthepocket.com/"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="transaction.php"> Trade Now</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="view.php"> Transactions  </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> Performance </a>
    </li>



    <li><a href="complete.php">History </a>
    </li>
    <li class="time">US Markets Open in&nbsp;<span id="hm_timer" class="style colorDefinition size_sm">08:20:04</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it this what you are looking for?

**Code:**

```css
.main-nav{
 color:#FFF;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#5e2d91;
 float:right;
 line-height:42px;
     margin-top: -3px;
 }
.main-nav ul li{
 display: inline;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    
 
}
.main-nav ul li a{
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 20px 14px;
 
}
.main-nav ul{
 margin-bottom:7px !important;}
.main-nav ul li a:hover {
 background-color:#0098aa;
}
.main-nav ul li a:active{
 
 background-color:#6A006A;
}
.time {
 float: right;
    background: #5e2d91;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #718b88;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 228px;
    height: 33px;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: right;
        line-height: 2.2;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://marketinthepocket.com/"> Home </a></li>
<li><a href="transaction.php"> Trade Now</a></li>

<li><a href="view.php"> Transactions  </a></li>
<li><a href=""> Performance </a></li>



<li><a href="complete.php">History </a></li>
<li class="time">US Markets Open in&nbsp;<span id="hm_timer" class="style colorDefinition size_sm">08:20:04</span> </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed at the top of the answer.

Comment: If this is what the questioner is looking for, I will explain.

Comment: I did not. Do not assume the downvoters comment or the commentors voted down

Comment: these are not working live This is th link of the live site : http://marketinthepocket.com   note: i have not float the time class in live code so may live design won't effect.