# Div Inside a Div Height Issue

Tags: html, css

I have a div with 15% Height and another div inside it with 15% height as well. Inner div has a `<p>` tag and this `<p>` tag is dropped out from the inner div but when I remove the height of the inner div everything works fine. Here is my `html` code and `CSS` code.

```css
.header {
  background-image: url("images/headerBg.jpg");
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  height: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>

  </div>


</div>
```

See below image for reference. Red thing is inner div and "Title" should be inside that Red thing but it's not html

[image]

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), there's some code missing.

Comment: your code is not properly replicating the issue; anyway it looks like the issue is because you haven't *cleared* your `float` - possible guidance / examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684091/html-list-isnt-vertically-aligned-when-using-floating-images/39684113#39684113), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311775/make-column-and-main-content-stay-on-left-or-right-as-browser-is-resized/39313556#39313556) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844984/content-move-down-when-i-apply-float-property/39845092#39845092)

Comment: @azeós Don't ask for a fiddle, ask for an inline [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Then what you except else? CSS code working as expected. It is taking 15% from it's parent nothing wrong there.

Comment: @kukkuz OP says _" but when i remove the height of inner div everything works fine."_, which indicates it has nothing to do with clearing float

Comment: @LGSon ohh that's true :) UsmanRiaz pls edit your question and add code that clearly replicates issue...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change height to min-height in .title class

```
.header{
   background-image:url("images/headerBg.jpg");
   height:15%;
   width:100%;
}
.title{
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  min-height:15%;
}
```

It will give you following view (I just use background-color instead of image, you can use whatever you want).

[image: With float left it will overlap the outer div]

You can remove float left and and play around with width.

This look will comes up if you will remove float left
[image: This look will comes up if you will remove float left]

And this look will comes up with width, I just added 100px, you can adjust it according to your requirements
[image: And this look will comes up with width, I just added 100px, you can adjust it according to your requirements]